# Retrieving the JSON data from function(err, data)

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb, quasar-framework

I am trying to retrieve the JSON data out from function(err, data) but was not able to do so. I have tried creating an array variable (`thisData`) to store the data but there is an error showing that:

> "Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render"

Is there a way I can possibly store the data into another variable so that I can access the data easily?

```
if (this.credentials) {
          console.log("in getReminder(), have credentials, getting reminder...");
          var thisData = [];

          documentClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
              console.error("Error getting reminder, err: ", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            }
            else {
              thisData = data;
              console.log("Success getting reminder: ", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

              if (data==null) {
                console.log("Data is null");
              }
              else {
                console.log("Data is not null");
              }
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: I have found out the causing error. There was a mistake for using "data" in my above code.